# how to get default end date in non-editable textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How to get Start Date and End Date using jquery.

For an example:
I need to get output:

**Start date** - 22/08/2016(should not be greater than today date and should not be auto-selected)

If a person select start date like today date ,end date should be filled automatically after one year date.

**End date**: 22/08/2017(by default in non-editable text box)

This my HTML code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
  <div id="fromdatetimepicker" class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-5" placeholder="Select a Start Date" />
    <a id="calIcon" class="input-group-addon btn btn-danger">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="travelInputName">End Date</label>
  <input  readonly type="text"   class="form-control" id="todatetimepicker">    
</div>
```

This my js code

```
jQuery("#fromdatetimepicker").datetimepicker({

  widgetPositioning: {
    horizontal: 'left',
    vertical: 'bottom'
  },
  allowInputToggle : true,
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  "minDate": moment()

});


jQuery("#todatetimepicker").datetimepicker({
  widgetPositioning: {
    horizontal: 'left',
    vertical: 'bottom'
  },
  allowInputToggle : true,
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',


});
```

[image: *this is my ui screen*]

Please, help me! How to do this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Which datetimepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: @SandeepNayak jquery plugin

Comment: could you please create a working fiddle for this with all javascript library references?

Answer (score 1):

Please modify "jQuery("#fromdatetimepicker").datetimepicker" event listener with below code and remove "jQuery("#todatetimepicker").datetimepicker" event listener as such it is redundant.

Please check below snppet.

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#fromdatetimepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      var dateText = dateText.split('/');
      var to_date = dateText[0]+'/'+dateText[1]+'/'+(parseInt(dateText[2])+1);
      jQuery("#todatetimepicker").val(to_date);
    }
  });
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="fromdatetimepicker" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-5" placeholder="Select a Start Date" />
    <a id="calIcon" class="input-group-addon btn btn-danger">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="travelInputName">End Date</label>
  <input  readonly type="text"   class="form-control" id="todatetimepicker">

</div>
```

Comment: thanku but this is not working ..this is taking by default today date as a start date as a editable text box and not showing calendar for start date and in end date empty textbox

Comment: thanks a ton ..maybe it's not working in my system bcoz some plugin is missing

Comment: Yeah or may be you are using different plugin to perform the datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
jQuery("#fromdatetimepicker").on("dp.change", function (e) {
  var start_date = e.date
  var end_date = start_date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);
  var todatetimepicker = jQuery('#todatetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker");
  todatetimepicker.date(end_date)
});
```

Comment: thanku for ur help ..but this is not showing calendar .

Comment: still same problem

Comment: comment the last two lines and alert the end_date..Find whether the problem is in setting the end_date or finding out the end_date. @seemachoudhary

Answer (score 0):

can u try this

```
$('#dob').datepicker({
onSelect: function(value, ui) {
    console.log(ui.selectedYear)
```

//        var op = New date calculation Here

```
    $('#datehidden').val(op);
},
maxDate: '+0d',
yearRange: '1920:2010',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
});
```